# Quintus Platformer

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a 2d platformer using Quintus.JS and i get a background to display with paralax and a animated sprite to display but I am having trouble displaying a `collisionLayer` with a `TileLayer`. I don't get any console errors and my `level.json` file is in the data directory.

My `tiles.png` file is 32x32 meaning in my `level.json` file is just a bunch of 0s.

This is the code where I think the error is occuring but I am not 100% sure.

```
Q.scene("level1", function(stage){
    stage.collisionLayer(new Q.TileLayer({
        dataAsset: 'level.json',
        sheet:     'tiles' }));
    stage.insert(new Q.Repeater({ 
        asset: "background-wall.png", 
        speedX: 0.5, 
        speedY: 0.5 }));
    var player = stage.insert(new Q.Player);
    stage.add("viewport").follow(player);
});
```

Here is what I have so far: http://personal.psu.edu/mtp5129/CataJump/

Comment: I wanted to help you, but maybe too late ;). I followed your link : http://personal.psu.edu/mtp5129/CataJump/ and it seems to use impactjs (not Quintus)